# What are some modern carousel library for android?

Tags: android, carousel

Is there any *library* available for *Carousel animation of images*?

I found http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/android-coverflow/ ; https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/ but this library/snippet use *extends gallay* (Gallery class was deprecated in API level 16. (4.1.2)), so is there any (modern) library? Maybe in combination with picasso?

Comment: [Check out this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475178/how-can-i-create-viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-preview-and-centred-one/35498701#35498701)

Comment: Try my project: https://github.com/vejei/CarouselView

Answer (score 13):

Here is the free link of **CarouselView** 
[Github Link](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview) and 
[Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3289)

**Gradle:**

```
compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.7'
```

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.synnapps</groupId> 
 <artifactId>carouselview</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.7</version>
 <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

**Usage:**
**Include following code in your layout:**

```
<com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
    android:id="@+id/carouselView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    app:pageColor="#00000000"
    app:radius="6dp"
    app:slideInterval="3000"
    app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"/>
```

**Include following code in your activity:**

```
public class SampleCarouselViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CarouselView carouselView;

int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_2, R.drawable.image_3, R.drawable.image_4, R.drawable.image_5};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_carousel_view);

    carouselView = (CarouselView) findViewById(R.id.carouselView);
    carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);

    carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);
}

ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
    @Override
    public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
        imageView.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
    }
};
```

}

If you want to add custom view, implement **ViewListener.**

```
public class SampleCarouselViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CarouselView customCarouselView;
int NUMBER_OF_PAGES = 5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_carousel_view);

    customCarouselView = (CarouselView) findViewById(R.id.customCarouselView);
    customCarouselView.setPageCount(NUMBER_OF_PAGES);
    // set ViewListener for custom view 
    customCarouselView.setViewListener(viewListener);
}

ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {

    @Override
    public View setViewForPosition(int position) {
        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_custom, null);
        //set view attributes here

        return customView;
    }
};
```

> For more information go to github link

Comment: It throws me FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.xxx.xxxxxx, PID: 10881
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: View must set ImageListener or ViewListener.

Comment: customCarouselView.setViewListener(viewListener);customCarouselView.setPageCount(NUMBER_OF_PAGES); first set viewlistner then set pagecount

Comment: Hi sir. i know this is already a long time post, but can i put a XML view in the last array in the carousel?

Answer (score 8):

I haven't found any such library available when searching for it, but when making my own app and using a `ViewPager` to display fragments, I've implemented my own class which implements [`ViewPager.PageTransformer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html).

**Though you've asked for a library**, I ran into a similar situation but ended up finding it easy enough to create my own class for it, so you may too. My guidance came from [Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer) in the Google Developer documentation. Here is my code:

```
public class CarouselPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        float scaleFactor = 0.5f;
        float rotationFactor = 20;

        if (position < 0) {
            page.setRotationY(rotationFactor * -position);
            float scale = 1 + scaleFactor * position;
            page.setScaleX(scale);
            page.setScaleY(scale);

        } else {
            page.setRotationY(rotationFactor * -position);
            float scale = 1 - scaleFactor * position;
            page.setScaleX(scale);
            page.setScaleY(scale);
        }
    }
}
```

The activity hosting the transform then calls:

`viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new CarouselPageTransformer());`

This code positions the `ViewPager`'s fragments to the sides of the visible screen, but you could just as easily position them to be visible, such as in the link you provided in your question.

Be aware of the minimum SDK required; from the documentation for `ViewPager.PageTransform`:

> As property animation is only supported as of Android 3.0 and forward, setting a PageTransformer on a ViewPager on earlier platform versions will be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

**Very Old Solution. Ignore**

I have tried searching a lot for an alternative to Carousel. I finally found the perfect alternative.

[InfiniteCycleViewPager](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4207)

This does just what the Carousel library does.

I modified it to load images from my SD card rather than Drawables.

Works Perfectly fine.

Comment: unfortunately library is not more supported :/

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setImageToCaroussel(){

    imgUrls.add("https://im.idiva.com//content/2015/May/salon_ettiquette1.jpg");
    imgUrls.add("https://www.womenfitness.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/What-to-look-for-when-choosing-a-hair-salon-1000x667.jpg");
    imgUrls.add("https://cdn.website.thryv.com/e3abe5c926184c4ca25389d43ae29913/dms3rep/multi/mobile/713b0a2.jpg");

    carouselView = (CarouselView) findViewById(R.id.carouselView);
    carouselView.setPageCount(imgUrls.size());

    carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);

}
 ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
    @Override
    public void setImageForPosition(final int position, final ImageView imageView) {

        Glide.with(ShopActivity.this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imgUrls.get(position))
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@Nullable Bitmap resource,@Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }

                });
    }
};
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

call `setImageListener` before `setPageCount` will resolve