# How to make recyclerview item bigger on click?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually I wanna make the current focused recyclerview item bigger than others . So I tried to refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33290906/8027365) .But it couldn't solve my issue so I wonder how to solve this issue.

Code:

```
public MyViewHolder(final View root) {
        super(root);
        root.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    // run scale animation and make it bigger
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(root.getContext(), R.anim.scale_in_tv);
                    root.startAnimation(anim);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                } else {
                    // run scale animation and make it smaller
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(root.getContext(), R.anim.scale_out_tv);
                    root.startAnimation(anim);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                }
            }
        });
        ButterKnife.bind(this, root);
    }
```

[image: I want effect like this image]

Comment: Is it the same Carousel behavior? Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747339/modern-carousel-library-for-android

Comment: No I'm asking to make the focused item bigger

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462253/viewpager-with-mutiple-visible-children-and-selected-bigger?lq=1

Comment: Why not setItemHeight bigger programmatically?