# Align to center muitple ImageViews side to side in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So, what I'm trying to get is something like:

```
img1                  img2                  img3
                       |
                       |
     I want it to be centered in this ImageView
```

Though what I'm getting is something like:

```
img 1                 img2                  img3
 |
 | 
It is centered in this ImageView
```

I've read a lot of questions like this one in this site but nothing helped me! I've seen people using `android:gravity="center"` or `android:layout_gravity="center"`. Nothing has helped me! I don't know what's the best option that I have. I would be grateful if someone helped me!

Here is my .xml file:

```
   <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrlVPrincipal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCard1"
            android:layout_width="259dp"
            android:layout_height="390dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.801"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCard2"
            android:layout_width="259dp"
            android:layout_height="390dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCard3"
            android:layout_width="259dp"
            android:layout_height="390dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Do you want to fix three images in screen with equal size each ?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar No. My intention is to make the second image the one that appears on the screen and then, if the user swipes left, the left image comes, and vice versa

Comment: U want to display only three image or more?

Comment: @NikunjPatel Just 3

Comment: U mean at that time only one image and after swipe another image show on screen

Comment: @NikunjPatel Exactly!

Comment: So u can use simply recycler view for that

Comment: @AndréSilva check this http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/carousel-layout-with-viewpager-in.html

Comment: and make raw layout for set set image into center

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747339/modern-carousel-library-for-android

Comment: **[`How to create Carousel Layout`](https://www.google.com/search?q=carousel+layout+in+android+site:stackoverflow.com&client=ubuntu&hs=zwo&channel=fs&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-rZrc6MPaAhVHNo8KHZKXByIQrQIIRSgEMAM&biw=1600&bih=727)**

Comment: @AndréSilva just use viewpager for that if you want to one image in center or visible only one image at a time.

Comment: you can do it by view pager. you can refer this link http://www.sanktips.com/2017/07/09/how-to-make-image-slider-with-viewpager-in-android-studio/